# determine whether the sequence $f_{n}(x) = n x e^{-nx}$ converges uniformly on the set [0,1]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the sequence $f_{n}(x) = n x e^{-nx}$  converges uniformly on the set [0,1].

**My trial:**

The pointwise limit is zero by L`hopitals rule , but then what how can I find N  so that  $|nxe^{-nx}| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to zero function. Then given  $\varepsilon \gt 0 $, there exists  $n_0\in \Bbb N $ such that  $|f_n(x)-0|<\varepsilon$, for all $n\geq n_0$ and $x\in [0,1]$. Note that  $$f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac1e .$$ Can you now find a suitable $\varepsilon$ which contradicts our assumption?

Comment: take $\epsilon = 0.1$ ...... is it correct?

Comment: The supremum is $1/n$ and not zero

Comment: @hopefully Yes, $0.1$ will work.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Find the maximum value of $f_n(x)$ on $[0,1]$. Does it approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$?